# php/javascript & string retrieved from database containing php&javascript variables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, variables, eval

I am trying to save javascript code for page in database as string so it will be easily editable from administration area instead of need to open file, edit it and upload to server. The problem is, that some of jQuery snippets are using PHP variables from settings ot $_GET variables to reload parts of site. The javascript alone retrieved from database works well but have no idea how to replace PHP variable into actual value. The code stored in database look like this but on generating page I want it to replace `$settings['countdown']` with `2016-07-01 22:00`

```
$("#clock").countdown("'.$settings['countdown'].'", function(event) {
    $(this).html(event.strftime("%-w week%!w:s; %-d days %-H:%M:%S"));
});
```

How am i able to make it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So far i used following solution and all seems working well:

Saving mentioned jQuery snippet into database as :

```
$(\"#clock\").countdown(\"{{settings.countdown}}\", function(event) {
    $(this).html(event.strftime(\"%-w week%!w:s; %-d days %-H:%M:%S\"));
});
```

and later render it with php like this:

```
if($page['js'] != ''){
    preg_match_all('#\{{(.*?)\}}#', $page['js'], $match);
    foreach($match[1] AS $k => $m){
        $m = explode('.', $match[1][$k]);
        if(isset($m[1])){
            $match[1][$k] = ${$m[0]}[$m[1]];
        }else{
            $match[1][$k] = $$m[0];
        }
        $page['js'] = str_replace($match[0][$k],$match[1][$k],$page['js']);
    }
    $jsfiles[] = '
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    '.$page['js'].'
    </script>';
}
```

Anyone can give any feedback for this?
Thanks